# Excel XML parser giving too many new lines for attribute nodes

Tags: xml, excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to use Excel to read some XML data so I can eventually save it all down to a single Excel/CSV file for use later, but I'm running into trouble with the way that some of the XML files are read by Excel's parser.  Here is an example of what the data looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<data>
<header>
    <name>n</name>
    <version>v</version>
    <date>d</date>
</header>
<abcd>
    <attr1>val1</attr1>
    <attr2>val2</attr2>
    <attr3>val3</attr3>
    <efgh>
        <attr4>val4</attr4>
        <attr5>val5</attr5>
        <attr6>val6</attr6>
        <ijkl>
            <attr7>val7</attr7>
            <attr8>val8</attr8>
            <attr9>val9</attr9>
        </ijkl>
    </efgh>
    <attr10>val10</attr10>
    <attr11>val11</attr11>
    <attr12>val12</attr12>
</abcd>
```

And the Excel XML parser found in the Data tab under `Data > From Other Sources > From XML Data Import` is giving me the output:

```
name | version | date | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | attr4 | attr5 | attr6
n      v         d      
                        val1    
                                val2    
                                        val3
                                                val4    val5    val6
```

But I would like the output to be:

```
name | version | date | attr1 | attr2 | attr3 | attr4 | attr5 | attr6
n      v         d      val1    val2    val3    val4    val5    val6
```

Or, in other words, I'd like every attribute value to be shown on the same line until the `<abcd>` tag comes up again.  Is there a way to coerce the Excel parser to do this?  Or, alternatively, is there an easy to way clean that data up after the fact using excel formulas or VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML is an open-dimension tree format where it can have as many nested elements as designed. However, spreadsheets, datasets, database tables, and other flat structures are two dimensions with row and column. Hence, you need to flatten your XML to a one child/one nest per row level structure for proper migration:

```
<data>
  <row>
    <col>value</col>
    <col>value</col>
    <col>value</col>
  </row>
  <row>
    <col>value</col>
    <col>value</col>
    <col>value</col>
  </row>
</data>
```

With VBA's [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms759204%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can flatten by running [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) (the special-purpose language designed to transform XML documents to various end use structural needs). Once transformed, you can load XML into Excel spreadsheet with [Workbooks.OpenXML()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838643.aspx).

**XSLT** Script *(save externally as .xsl to be loaded in VBA)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:copy>            
      <xsl:apply-templates select="abcd"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="abcd">
    <row>
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::data/header/*"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="attr1|attr2|att3"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="efgh"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="attr10|attr11|attr12"/>
    </row>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="efgh">    
      <xsl:copy-of select="attr4|attr5|attr6"/>      
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ijkl"/>    
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ijkl">    
      <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**VBA** Macro

```vb
Public Sub RunXSLT()
    Dim xmlDoc As Object, xslDoc As Object, newDoc As Object

    Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set xslDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    Set newDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL DOCS '
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Input.xml"
    xmlDoc.async = False

    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLTScript.xsl"
    xslDoc.async = False

    ' TRANSFORM SOURCE TO OUTPUT ' 
    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    Set newDoc = Nothing
    Set xslDoc = Nothing
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing

    ' IMPORT OUTPUT INTO WORKBOOK ' 
    Workbooks.OpenXML "C:\Path\To\Output.xml", , xlXmlLoadImportToList

End Sub
```

**XML** Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <row>
        <name>n</name>
        <version>v</version>
        <date>d</date>
        <attr1>val1</attr1>
        <attr2>val2</attr2>
        <attr4>val4</attr4>
        <attr5>val5</attr5>
        <attr6>val6</attr6>
        <attr7>val7</attr7>
        <attr8>val8</attr8>
        <attr9>val9</attr9>
        <attr10>val10</attr10>
        <attr11>val11</attr11>
        <attr12>val12</attr12>
    </row>
</data>
```

**Excel** import

```
name  version   date    attr1   attr2   attr4   attr5   attr6   attr7   attr8   attr9   attr10  attr11  attr12
  n         v      d     val1    val2    val4    val5    val6    val7    val8    val9    val10   val11   val12
```